# Define a Cucumber step in a Before block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

```
Before('@scoped_step')
  Given(/^Some step$/) do
    puts "Success!"
  end
end
```

However, Cucumber just thinks I'm trying to call a step:

```
WARNING: Using 'Given/When/Then' in step definitions is deprecated, use 'step' to call other steps instead
```

I'm trying to track down how to do this via the Cucumber code base, but I'm getting a bit lost.

Any ideas how to achieve this? Something like "Cucumber::Steps.register_step(...)`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to define a step in a before hook? This does not seem like the right approach. If you give more context, perhaps someone can suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: Scoped steps: Only have some steps active in a given feature/scenario.